# How to show $g(x) = 4x^3 - 2x \leq -2$ for $x \leq -1$

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x) = 4x^3 − 2x.$

(a) Find and classify all the local maxima and minima of $g$. [DONE]

(b) Show that $g(x) \leq −2$ for $x \leq −1$

Comment: It would be good if you could add your thoughts on the problem or what you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

(b): we have $g(-1)=-2$ and $g'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \le -1$.

Hence, $g$ is increasing on $(- \infty,-1]$, thus, if $x \le -1$ then we have $g(x) \le g(-1)=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it suffices to prove that $2x^{3}-x+1 \leq 0$ for all $x \leq -1$. But
$x \leq -1$ implies that
$$
2x^{3}-x+1 = x(2x^{2}-1)+1 \leq -2x^{2}+2 \leq 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Without calculus, note for $x\le -1$:
$$4x^3-2x\le -2 \iff 2x^3-x+1\le 0 \iff (\underbrace{x+1}_{\le 0})(\underbrace{2x^2-2x+1}_{>0})\le 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Regards @Matthew , this is similar (slighty different view) to @Fred 's answer. Define $$ G(x) = 4x^{3} - 2x + 2, \:\:\: x \le -1 $$ then
$$ G'(x) = 12 x^{2} - 2 > 0  $$
so we have $G(x)$ is increasing for $x \le -1$. But
$$ G(-1) = -4 + 2+ 2 = 0 $$
So we must have $G(x) = 4x^{3} - 2x + 2 < 0$ for $x < -1$, or
$$ 4x^{3} - 2x < - 2 $$
So we get 
$$ g(x) = 4x^{2} - 2x \le -2, \:\: x \le -1 $$
Thanks.